# Concat using update contact activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am using **Salesforce data** as the entry event in Journey builder.

I have two fields from the journey data which I want to concat and I am using **Update Contact** activity to do this in Journey builder using the below code for the **Attribute value** but this isn't working.

{{event.DEexternalkey.nameofthefield}}{{event.DEexternalkey.nameofthefield}}

[image]

How should i write this? I am new to api language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like special characters like ":" have special processing and just do not work as expected.

You can wrap the field name with double quotes (`"<field>"`) so it gets treated as a full field name, like this:

`{{event.DEexternalkey."nameofthefield"}} {{event.DEexternalkey."nameofthefield"}}`

It should work fine this way.

Comment: No joy! I followed this article to find the eventkey. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390236&type=1. I found this. {{Event.SalesforceObj826c8b1e06799ed4d8c868ef6f0f4a59.”Case:Contact:Email”}} I tried several iterations of this but none of them seem to work. I cannot find a DEAudience-key as its mentioned in the article.

Comment: I got it working now using this. UniqueID = {{Event.SalesforceObj826c8b1e06799ed4d8c868ef6f0f4a59."Case:Contact:Email"}}
I had to redo the quotes inside the editor.